# Create new folder with timestamp and then move files to new folder

Tags: python, timestamp, shutil

I'm having trouble with this ... I want to create a new folder with a time stamped name. Then I want to move a bunch of files into it.

I can't figure it out!

```
import shutil, os, time   
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
Sourcepath = r'Z:\\test'
if not os.path.exists(Sourcepath):
        os.makedirs(Sourcepath+timestr)
source = os.listdir(Sourcepath)    
destinationpath = (Sourcepath+timestr)     
for files in source:
    if files.endswith('.json'):      
shutil.move(os.path.join(source,files),os.path.join(destinationpath,files))
```

Comment: please indent each line of your code with four spaces (more if your code is indented more). Then it will be much clearer to read.

Comment: what exactly happens when you run your code?  Do you get a traceback? or just not the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix your problem.  Notice indentation of last line

```
import shutil, os, time   
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
Sourcepath = r'Z:\\test'
if not os.path.exists(Sourcepath):
        os.makedirs(Sourcepath+timestr)
source = os.listdir(Sourcepath)    
destinationpath = (Sourcepath+timestr)     
for files in source:
    if files.endswith('.json'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source,files),os.path.join(destinationpath,files))
```